# Admin bar is disabled in front

Tags: admin, admin-bar

I'm having a problem and i cant find any solution at all.
i have a wordpress site with a theme and all of a suddenn after changing only the footer height with css
it dissapeared the content of the footer and also the admin bar.
When i deleted the css changes it still had the same problem!

After i checked some answers i did this

1) Toolbar is enabled from my users profile

2) Here are the header.php and index.php and footer.php .

Header.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>

    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>

    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

    <?php
    /**
     * Wordpress Head. This is REQUIRED! Never remove the wp_head
     */
    wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<?php $bw_dfb = Bw::get_option('default_frame_color'); ?>
<?php $bw_eip = Bw::get_option('enable_image_protection'); ?>

<body <?php body_class( Bw::body_class( esc_attr( Bw::get_body_class() ) ) ); if( $bw_dfb ): ?> data-default-frame="<?php echo esc_attr( $bw_dfb ); ?>"<?php endif; ?>>

    <?php if( $bw_eip ): ?><span id="image-protection"><?php Bw::the_option('img_protection_text', 'Hey, this photo is &copy;'); ?></span><?php endif; ?>

    <?php // get_template_part('templates/demos'); ?>

    <span id="bw-preloader" class="no-pointer bw-pre-animation bw-opt-anim"></span>

    <?php get_template_part('templates/frame-border'); ?>

    <div id="mobile-menu-panel">
        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'mobile' ) ) : ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mobile', 'container_class' => 'bw-mobile-menu' ) ); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p><?php _e('Please select mobile menu.', BW_THEME); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <?php get_template_part( 'templates/header/' . Bw::get_option('header_layout', 'standard') ); ?>

        <div id="container" class="">
```

index.php :

```
<?php

/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="djax-dynamic <?php if( get_post_type() == 'post' ) { echo 'right'; } ?>">

    <?php echo '<div class="panama-no-heading"></div>'; ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content/content' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content/content-none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Footer.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 * @package Bad Weather
 */
?>
    </div> <!-- #container -->
</div> <!-- #wrapper -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see all php functions are in the right place.

I also tried with another administrator account.
in the functions.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Bad Weather Framework Initiation, load bootstrap
 */

require get_template_directory() . '/bw/bootstrap.php';

?>
```

Also changed the plugins folder name to something else to see if any plugin is causing the mess, but still the problem resists.

inside the admin-bar.php

```
function is_admin_bar_showing() {
    global $show_admin_bar, $pagenow;

    // For all these types of requests, we never want an admin bar.
    if ( defined('XMLRPC_REQUEST') || defined('DOING_AJAX') || defined('IFRAME_REQUEST') )
        return false;

    if ( is_embed() ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Integrated into the admin.
    if ( is_admin() )
        return true;

    if ( ! isset( $show_admin_bar ) ) {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
            $show_admin_bar = false;
        } else {
            $show_admin_bar = _get_admin_bar_pref();
        }
    }
```

[image]
Can someone help me please?

P.S. the same problem is with firefox, chrome incognito, microsoft edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check admin bar is showing in WP admin. So go to :

```
Users -> YOUR_PROFILE
```

One of the check boxes : “Show Toolbar when viewing site” — make sure that’s checked on .

Then if it's ok add this code to your `functions.php` :

```
function admin_bar(){

  if(is_user_logged_in()){
         add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' , 1000 );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'admin_bar' );
```

Comment: oh my god i almost go crazy with this. Thanks a lot man it worked 100% !!!!!! And i mean the code in functions.php  because the "Show toolbar" option was checked.